# Flutter: Converting Map Structure

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to convert the structure of a Map in Flutter before uploading to Firestore to get around some of Firestore's query limitations (ie, multiple array-contains limitation).

I have the following Map structure:

```
{
  dog: [brown, black], 
  cat: [brown]
}
```

However, I would like to convert that to:

```
{
  dog: true,
  cat: true,
  colors: [brown, black],
}
```

I can then perform a query such as:

```
.where('animals.dog', isEqualTo: true)
.where('category.color', arrayContains: color)
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: I didn't get you, but you can try to perform this query .where('animals.dog',arrayContains: color) so if the color exists that means dog also exists , you dont have to use true or false in that  case .

Comment: I didn't think of it like that - you are an absolute lifesaver!! Thank you!

Comment: Always welcome <3